# Trouble turning a Simple MsSQL select into a monitor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, monitoring

I have a SQL Statement that works as I want.

```
select COUNT(*), MIN(emailed_to)from email.email_archive
group by emailed_to
order by COUNT(*) desc
```

The output looks like this.

```
13   deadlockIE12388nnhy32@hepmeplease.com;
8   deadlockIE1277yhygt@hepmeplease.com;
4   deadlockFF17uyt9xx967@hepmeplease.com;
...
...
...
1       deadlockFF17uytsdfa7@hepmeplease.com;
```

This is simple enough, but then I would have to remember to run the select every day and make sure things are ok.  I want to have the stored procedure email me once in a while and I can decide if I have an issue.  So I have hacked together the following from many resources:

```
use MYDB;
go
IF SCHEMA_ID('monitors') IS NULL EXECUTE('CREATE SCHEMA monitors AUTHORIZATION dbo')
GO
if object_id('monitors.email_abuse') is null
 exec('create procedure monitors.email_abuse as print ''stub'' return');
GO
alter procedure monitors.email_abuse
    (@to    varchar(max) = 'itops@hepmeplease.com',
     @sendemail tinyint = 1)
as
set nocount on ;
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted ;
begin try
declare     @errmsg     varchar(max) = '',
        @subject    nvarchar(255);
select @subject = 'Run Away Email Monitor';
select @errmsg = REPLICATE(char(10),1)+
        '# of Emails'+
         REPLICATE(char(9),1)+
         'Email Address'+
         REPLICATE(CHAR(10),1); 
select @errmsg = @errmsg +REPLICATE(char(9),1)+
    CAST(COUNT(*) as CHAR(10))+
    REPLICATE(char(9),1)+ 
    CAST(MIN(emailed_to) as CHAR(45))
from 
    email.email_archive
group by 
    emailed_to
order by 
    COUNT(*) desc;
print @errmsg;
    if @sendemail = 1
    begin
        exec master.dbo.sp_email 
            @to = @to,
            @subject = @subject,
            @body = @errmsg;
    end
end try
begin catch
    -- unexpected errors
    exec sp_raise_error @rethrow = 1, @textdata = N'Error in monitors.email_abuse', @emailTo = N'itops@hepmeplease.com'
    end catch
go
```

But it then emails me the following output that is just one line.  I know that there are many lines but for some reason when I put the `COUNT(*), MIN(emailed_to)` into the `CAST` statement this no longer works.  I get a email that has the header and one line.  If I just print the output of @errmsg I exactly what I get in the email, the header and the one line. just like below.

```
# of Emails  Email Address
    1           y@y.com;
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with my cast statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

My guess is that the code you are actually using is slightly different from the code you have posted here because when I take your code and the following data in a test database, things work out fine.

```
create table email_archive
(
    id int,
    emailed_to nvarchar(255)
)

insert into email_archive values
    ( 1, 'one@helpme.com'), ( 2, 'two@helpme.com'), ( 3, 'three@helpme.com'),
    ( 4, 'four@helpme.com'), ( 5, 'one@helpme.com'), ( 6, 'two@helpme.com'),
    ( 7, 'three@helpme.com'), ( 8, 'four@helpme.com'), ( 9, 'one@helpme.com'),
    (10, 'two@helpme.com'), (11, 'three@helpme.com'), (12, 'four@helpme.com'),
    (13, 'one@helpme.com'), (14, 'two@helpme.com'), (15, 'three@helpme.com'),
    (16, 'four@helpme.com'), (17, 'one@helpme.com'), (18, 'one@helpme.com'),
    (19, 'one@helpme.com'), (20, 'three@helpme.com'), (21, 'three@helpme.com')
```

I am thinking you may have hit upon an issue discussed here: http://bit.ly/cMlnjt

Since I can't be sure I offer you two alternative solutions that will definitely get the job done, even though *as others have mentioned* this aggregate concatenation *should* work without an issue.

**Alternatives:**

To get what you are looking for, I prefer one of the following two options

1) Just make sp_send_dbmail do the work for you.

2) Go with a cursor solution

**Option 1:**

```
EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail    @profile_name = 'MyMailProfile', 
                        @recipients = 'my_email@domain.com',
                        @subject = 'Runaway Email Monitor',
                        @body = 'Runaway emails found',
                        @query = 'SELECT COUNT(*), emailed_to FROM mydb.dbo.email_archive GROUP BY emailed_to HAVING COUNT(*) > 5 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC'
```

Note: The having clause makes this only display rows where the count is greater than 5.

**Option 2:**

```
USE test

IF EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM test.sys.sysobjects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'usp_MonitorEmails' )
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.usp_MonitorEmails
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MonitorEmails
    @Subject nvarchar(255) = '',
    @Importance varchar(6) = 'NORMAL',
    @Sensitivity varchar(12) = 'NORMAL',
    @Recipients varchar(MAX) = NULL,
    @MinimumCount int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF UPPER(@Importance) NOT IN ('LOW', 'NORMAL', 'HIGH') SET @Importance = 'NORMAL'
    IF UPPER(@Sensitivity) NOT IN ('NORMAL', 'PERSONAL', 'PRIVATE', 'CONFIDENTIAL') SET @Sensitivity = 'NORMAL'


    DECLARE @run bit,
            @message nvarchar(MAX)

    SELECT  @run = 0,
            @subject =  'Run Away Email Monitor',
            @message =  'Run away emails found' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 
                        'Count        Email Address' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 
                        '-----------  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    DECLARE @count int, 
            @email nvarchar(255)
    DECLARE BodyCursor CURSOR STATIC FOR
        SELECT COUNT(*), emailed_to FROM email_archive GROUP BY emailed_to HAVING COUNT(*) > @MinimumCount ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    OPEN BodyCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM BodyCursor
        INTO @count, @email

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @message = @message + REPLICATE(N' ', 11-LEN(CAST(@count AS nvarchar(22)))) + CAST(@count AS nvarchar(22)) + '  ' + @email + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), @run = 1

        FETCH NEXT FROM BodyCursor
            INTO @count, @email
    END
    CLOSE BodyCursor
    DEALLOCATE BodyCursor

    IF @run = 1 AND LEN(@Recipients) > 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail   @profile_name = 'MyMailProfile', 
                                    @recipients = @Recipients,
                                    @subject = @Subject,
                                    @body = @Message,
                                    @body_format = 'TEXT',
                                    @importance = @Importance,
                                    @sensitivity = @Sensitivity
    END
END

GO
```

**Note:** I prefer this method because of the flexibility I have in the way the messages are formatted.  This will also *only* send the email if there are rows returned where the  minimum count is reached.

Comment: I agree that as the OP is on SQL Server 2008 they should avoid this approach as better ones exist than that SQL Server 2000 method but you seem to be saying at the top of the post that this approach won't work and is documented to set the variable to the value of the last row. That is the bit I was disagreeing with.

Comment: When I wrote this last night I was receiving the same results as the OP, so I offered two alternative solutions.  In the office now I am able to run the aggregate concatenation without issue.  I did stumble upon this http://bit.ly/cMlnjt which explains why this might be happening (I believe I may have been doing something extra in my query last night to cause this issue.) I wonder if the OP has made changes to the code he is actually using for this post, because running his code here, I get the expected result... although I still think using sp_send_dbmail though is the easiest way here.

Comment: Thanks for the update Martin, I just changed my comments here to reflect the latest.  I am going to alter my answer to include the new info because you are correct, the first bit is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You will only get one value because you have no loop through the recordset containing the emails. You will need to use a [`CURSOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) to traverse the set and build up your `@errmsg` variable with the contents of each record.

Nimble SQL jockeys will probably point out you could avoid the `CURSOR` with the correct kind of join in the query but I always find that harder than this method and if it doesn't have to be high performance it does the job.

Here's some example code;

```
DECLARE @myGlobalVar nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @myVarCol1 nvarchar(10); 
DECLARE @myVarCol2 nvarchar(10);

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1
WHERE wanted = 1
ORDER BY col1;

OPEN myCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor 
INTO @myVarCol1, @myVarCol2;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT @myGlobalVar = @myGlobalVar + ' ' + @myVarCol1 + ' ' + @myVarCol2;

  FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor 
  INTO @myVarCol1, @myVarCol2;
END
CLOSE vendor_cursor;
DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor;
```

Always remember to `FETCH NEXT` inside the loop unless you want to have to kill the process! You should always `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` the cursor too or you'll run out of memory eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues when trying to use this approach to concatenation in the past. Often some messing around with the SELECT resolves it. The FOR XML approach to concatenation is more robust.

I tried to reproduce the issue here though and couldn't (it worked correctly for me and output the 2 different email addresses in the concatenation).

Does this work for you? If so maybe compare the execution plans and see what's different.

```
set nocount on

create table #email_archive
(
emailed_to CHAR(45)
)

insert into #email_archive
select 'deadlockIE12388nnhy32@hepmeplease.com;' union all
select 'deadlockIE12388nnhy32@hepmeplease.com;' union all
select 'deadlockIE12388nnhy32@hepmeplease.com;' union all
select 'deadlockIE12388nnhy32@hepmeplease.com;' union all
select 'deadlockIE12388nnhy32@hepmeplease.com;' union all
select 'deadlockIE12388nnhy32@hepmeplease.com;' union all
select 'deadlockIE12388nnhy32@hepmeplease.com;' union all
select 'deadlockIE12388nnhy32@hepmeplease.com;' union all
select 'deadlockIE1277yhygt@hepmeplease.com;'


declare @errmsg     varchar(max) = '',
        @subject    nvarchar(255) = 'Run Away Email Monitor';

select @errmsg = REPLICATE(char(10),1)+
        '# of Emails'+
         REPLICATE(char(9),1)+
         'Email Address'+
         REPLICATE(CHAR(10),1); 

select @errmsg = @errmsg +REPLICATE(char(9),1)+
    CAST(COUNT(*) as CHAR(10))+
    REPLICATE(char(9),1)+ 
    CAST(MIN(emailed_to) as CHAR(45))
from 
    #email_archive
group by 
    emailed_to
order by 
    COUNT(*) desc;

print @errmsg;
drop table #email_archive;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above were all great answers..but the simplest of all came from Mike Talley overnight.

```
select @errmsg = @errmsg +REPLICATE(char(9),1)+
    CAST(COUNT(*) as CHAR(10))+
    REPLICATE(CHAR(9),1)+
    cast(substring(emailed_to, 1, 45) as char(45))+
    REPLICATE(CHAR(10),1)
```

Once I dropped the MIN and added in the substring the monitor worked like a charm..